# Extremely slow Postgres query that runs fast in Oracle

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

So i just started working in PostgreSQL after some experience with Oracle and I have this query, that in Oracle returns in 200ms and in Postgres returns in 1.40 mins. The culprit seems to be

```
AND product_cost_view.product_type_id = product.product_type_id
```

When i remove this portion or hardcode `product_cost_view.product_type_id` with some ID, it runs fast. Explain plan didn't seem give and insight, it just says `INDEX SCAN ON TABLE product TOTAL COST 776403 1913 ROWS`.

Yes, product_cost_view is a view, I've also remarked that if i replace that view with a table that also has product_type_id then it also works fast. I tried using `CTE` and `subselects` in 100 different forms but when i use that product.product_type_id in the where clause with that view it just works hellish slow and i can't see what I miss. Thanks in advance :)
P.S. Yes, i have the exact same data and indexes in both databases

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM product
WHERE user_id = 1000000
  AND (product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id
                        FROM product_cost_view
                        WHERE user_id = 1000000
                          AND cost_type = 'X'
                          AND product_cost_view.product_type_id = product.product_type_id)
    );
```

Comment: Note that the `distinct` in the subquery is completely useless. Oracle might optimize it away, but I don't think Postgres will

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this variant:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.product_id)
FROM product P
INNER JOIN product_cost_view PC
    ON P.product_id = PC.product_id
    AND P.user_id = PC.user_id
    AND P.product_type_id = PC.product_type_id
WHERE P.user_id = 1000000
    AND PC.cost_type = 'X'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fast now! Can you give any insight on why it was slow in the first form?

Comment: Well, its hard to tell without running the code in your environment, but from my practice I see a lot of cases, when the SQL Engine (SQL Server, PosgreSQL, Oracle) are not building the correct plans if the query is too complex. So, I just try to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `DISTINCT`, PostgreSQL cannot flatten the subquery into a join, so you are running the subquery for every row found in `product`.

Hard to say for certain without seeing the execution plan, but this should be faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM product AS p
WHERE p.user_id = 1000000
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_cost_view AS pc
              WHERE pc.product_type_id = p.product_type_id
                AND pc.product_id = p.product_id
                AND pc.user_id = 1000000
                AND pc.cost_type = 'X');
```